# Are the icons used on the WMD editor on Stack Overflow going to be changed?

Tags: support, editor, privileges-page

Are the icons used for the WMD editor shown on *Stack Overflow* going to be changed?

The reason I am asking is that the Hyperlink icon shown on the "Remove New User Restrictions" privilege page on Stack Exchange sites doesn't match with the icon used from the WMD editor on those sites.

This is what that privilege page shows on [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).

> [image: screenshot]

The icons used by the WMD editor on the same site are the following.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Most curiously, that icon on the help page is on imgur instead of the CDN.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby The privilege pages are CW pages, on this very site; on the other sites, they are copied from the equivalent privilege page on this site. Since there isn't a way to refer one of the images used on the WMD editor, the only way is to add an image to the CW post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think it's about change, but rather that each site has its own editor "theme" aka CSS sprites file defining the icons we see.

I guess that it's built as part of the site design once it's launched out of Beta.

Some examples: (live)

- Stack Overflow:
  [image]
- Meta:
  [image]
  <sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/Img/wmd-buttons.png))</sub>
- Arcade/Gaming:
  [image]
- Drupal:
  [image]

In my opinion there are two options for correct behavior:

1. Make it the same in all sites, same way the blockquote icon and code block icon are same.
2. Have the privilege page show correct icon for each site, maybe dynamically somehow.